# Source material to learn parametric equations

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation

Anyone know any good source material to learn how to parametrize curves in a methodical way, because when i see someone parametrize a curve looks intuitive, but for me it isn't.

thanks !

Comment: thanks a lot !!

Comment: The book I learned to do this with is Vector Calculus Fourth Edition, by Susan Jane Colley. But as Bye_World says, any undergrad vector calculus book should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these will be useful: https://www.math.uh.edu/~jiwenhe/Math1432/lectures/lecture14_handout.pdf
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUqm50iMOpA
I have a real book about it actually but If you don't understand Macedonian it won't be useful :)
Good luck!

Comment: i liked the material tkx a lot